# Simple HTML auto indentation tool

Tags: html, tools

I have made the mistake of not indenting the HTML tags on a page that slowly grew to over 500 lines of dense HTML. I have looked for a tool to fix the indentation, but what I have found so far seem to insist on doing additional formatting, and I really don't need those 500 lines to become 1000 because big bunches of small tags get one line per tag.

Any suggestions for a tool to do the job?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't tell us which tools you tried so far, but the first that comes to my mind is HTML Tidy: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sorry, yes I tried Tidy, though only with a webpage interface. I can't get it to not inject a bunch of lineshifts, it's quite bad with tables, two lines per td element is way too much. It also feature messing up the JavaScript and CSS tab indentation.

Comment: @ebus Tidy has a LOT of configuration options, I recommend you try it in http://www.htmlkit.com/ where it can be configured via a nice GUI

Answer (score 0):

The [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) IDEs allow you to reformat your code based on a set of rules, so you can get as detailed or as simple as you want. If this is a one-time thing, you could always use the trial copy of whichever one is most appropriate for you to reformat your code.

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is probably your best bet, although if you're developing your web applications with [PHP](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [Ruby on Rails](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), or a few other languages, they have you covered there, too.

Comment: Seems like it may be able to do the job, gotta experiment a bit more to get it just right though. Hadn't imagined this would be so complicated. Performance is pretty bad when working with a 100kB file by the way.